# If Task.GetAwaiter().GetResult() in ASP.NET stop all threads?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, task

Consider this constructor in `ASP.NET` app:

```
private readonly IRepository _repository;

public class SomeController(IRepositoryProvider repositoryProvider)
{
    _repository = repositoryProvider.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}
```

My question is, if something go wrong that constructor will block whole app for a while or only current thread where request from `SomeController` were executed?

Comment: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html

Comment: @Milney great post, thanks! But still it is not answer to my question

Comment: Why would it block the whole app? It will block the thread processing that request - although it may also cause a deadlock with the thread assigned to performing the async work, so potentially two threads could be blocked. The article mainly says - you shouldn't do that in the first place (async work in sync constructor), so the question is kindof moot, because you shouldn't do it that way anyway